# How to properly an catch exception

Tags: java, exception

So I have to take inputs via a scanner. I'm trying to get the program to keep asking the user for a valid input when they enter a non-integer value. Here's how I attempted to make that happen.

```
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int level=0;

    try{
        level=input.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println(e+". Enter a valid entry!");
        level=input.nextInt();
    }
```

The problem is that the program doesn't let the user enter another integer if they've entered a character. The program just stops and prints out the print statement in the catch block as well as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:20) (which is level=input.nextInt(); in the catch block)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is what happens when Scanner throws an exception. The Java documentation says:

"When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method"

so that's why your 2nd call to nextInt throws another exception - it's trying to re-read the same token. If you want to discard it, you can just call next.

The 2nd issue is that your code will only allow the user to re-enter a value once. If they mistype things a 2nd time you're out of luck. I suggest something like this:

```
int level = 0;
boolean gotLevel = false;

while (!gotLevel) {
  try {
    level = input.nextInt();
    gotLevel = true;
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Error. " + input.next() + " is not a valid integer:" + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this seems correct, would you mind marking the question as answered?

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to this